# Getting all elements of Given name of json element in Perl

Tags: json, perl

I have a JSON element let say

```
"profile": 
     {"name":"ankush", 
      "children":
             "web":[ 
                 {"children":
                       {"web":"hello"}
                 },
        {"hk":"fdf"}
                 ]
     }
```

I have to get all the nodes `web` in Perl. Can someone please suggest some function of 
JSON that can give me all instances of "web". Means I dont want to iterate infinitely until I get all instances Just one call and thats it. 
Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Install and use on of the JSON modules, for example [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON%3a%3aPP).

The module will read the JSON and give you a perl data structure (array or hash reference).